# Compiz crashing when alt-tabbing from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: 16.04, compiz, 16.10, intellij

So I've been having this problem where the screen would freeze for 1 second and then it seems it would revive itself but all my open programs would've been terminated. After this freezing it would say that Compiz has crashed (I've reported the crash several times through this error popup). One thing I've noticed is it consistently happens only when I'm on IntelliJ IDEA then I'd alt-tab to something else (most of the time it's Google Chrome). This happens around once a day for maybe 3-4 hrs a day of Intellij usage.

This started happening when I was still on 16.04, but after updating to 16.10 it still happens. The difference I've noticed is that back in 16.04 when the freezing happened, it would leave all my programs still running (but still show the Compiz error popup). On 16.10 it kills all my open programs. That's why I didn't mind it back in 16.04 but now it's getting really troublesome if I'm in the middle of something and it would close everything. Any ideas? I've also updated IntelliJ several times.

Lenovo Z500, Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit with all updates always installed, still using Unity as my display manager. Windows 10 64-bit is installed side by side in this laptop, but GRUB is the one handling the booting.

Comment: Can you try a different DE like KDE or XFCE?

Comment: I have not encountered this and I have the same hardware with 16.04, except I use Android Studio (which is IntelliJ I believe) and I use Firefox instead of Chrome (except for Netflix) - Also I am running openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: I also alt-tab between Android Studio and Chrome, but my hardware is completely different...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Yeah, I also use Android Studio sometimes and I think it has also happened for AS if I recall correctly (memory unsure though).

Comment: As for trying out a different DE, I think I'll go ahead and try it, but then it will take a few days to know for sure if it was fixed because this problem happens around once a day. Thanks though :)

Comment: That's the piece of information you left out. That seems to be your issue so consider _re-installing_ your former desktop.